# Scala. How can I take a value from Future on success, on failure throw exception?

Tags: scala, refactoring, future

I have a code (the `getServiceBySid` function returns `Future[ServiceCategory]`):

```
var service: ServiceCategory =
      Await.result((for {
        optService <- getServiceBySid(serviceSid)
      } yield {
        optService
      }) recover {
        case e: Throwable =>
          throw e
      }, Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

and I can't stop thinking that this code is not in true style of Scala. Actually it does something like

```
val serviceCategory: ServiceCategory = 
      getServiceCategoryBySid(serviceCategorySid) onComplete {
        case Success(value) => value
        case Failure(e) => throw e
      }
```

but onComplete returns `Unit`, so it doesn't work. How can I refactor the code?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Is it not working? What do you want to change? "true style" is very subjective. For starter, you usually wouldn't use `Await.result` since it's blocking. But then again, maybe there's a reason there.

Comment: @mfirry too many brackets. the code seems too ugly for me

Comment: "True Scala style" would return `Future[ServiceCategory]` because "true Scala style" would not `Await()` and would not `throw`.

Comment: @jwvh so you are welcome to fix all of that! I also want to get rid of the `Await()`. Also, what you suggest instead of `throw`, if program should throw an exception in case of exception.

Comment: What is the point of using **Futures** if you are going to await them? Also, if all your program is composed in one big future, if one of the inner futures fail, then all will fail and the program will crash with the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write

```
Await.result(getServiceBySid(serviceSid), Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
```

because if you `Await.result` on `Future` it will return the value if succeeded or throw exception caught by failed `Future`.